# Running Lighthouse reports from command line creates reports for mobile. Is there a way to create reports with a choice between desktop&mobile?

Tags: lighthouse

I created a text file with a list of URLs, installed NodeJS and Lighthouse.
Created a batch file PageSpeedURLs.bat:

```
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\Test\urls.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless"
```

Ran the following from command line:
`lighthouse PageSpeedReports.bat`

The reports seem to be for mobile browser rather than desktop.
Is there any option to specify mobile or desktop here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an option --form-factor and determine desktop or mobile.

For example on your script:

```
    @For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\Test\urls.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --form-factor="desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the desktop version instead of mobile device, update the lighthouse command with `--preset=desktop`. For example,

`lighthouse https://www.google.com/ --preset=desktop`